# Calculate Refractive index of sapphire with sellmeier equation

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to calculate the refracrive index of Sapphire with the Sellmeier equation. i defined the equation but now i cant figure out how to input the wavelengths in nanometers.  see code below...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def nsell( lam ):

B1=1.023798
B2=1.058264
B3=5.280792
C1=0.0614482
C2=0.110700
C3=17.92656

lam=lam*10**-9

nsq = 1   + [B1] * lam**2 / (lam **2 - [C1])
nsq = nsq + [B2] * lam**2 / (lam **2 - [C2])
nsq = nsq + [B3] * lam**2 / (lam **2 - [C3])

return nsq**0.5


Lab=np.linspace(300,400,20)
test=nsell(Lab)
print(test)
```

i get weird result or i just do not understand it.

```
runfile('C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/Python Scripts/ligei.py', wdir='C:/Users/Kevin/Documents/Python Scripts')
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.
  1.  1.]
```

Comment: Wavelength for visible light is usually given in nm, I understand from your definition of `Lab` that you stick to this convention(though it is barely in the visible range). Never heard of this Sellmeier equation, but [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sellmeier_equation) that the coefficients are given for wavelengths in µm. You should convert your wavelengths with `lam /= 1000` into µm. I would do my calculation first with BK7 values and compare my results with those in the Wikipedia diagram.

Comment: @Piinthesky Thank you for your comment. i did as you suggested to calculate the BK7 values for 600-2000 nm and it worked. I guess i went the units went over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficients you are using appear to be based on micrometers, so you have to use micrometers for lambda as well. Just use

```
Lab=np.linspace(0.3,0.4,20)
```

Since it looks like you want 300 nm to 400 nm, which is 0.3 um to 0.4 um.

Alternatively, you could convert your coefficients to the units you want to use.

Also, the square brackets around your coefficients are unnecessary.

Comment: If you suggest this, then you have to adjust the step size as well.

Comment: `np.linspace` uses the number of steps, not the step size (unlike `np.arange`).